# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException : Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 1

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting android: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException

**Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 1: /data/data/com.tuto.ListViewApp2_SQLite/databases/countryDB**

When i run the emulator it does not start, it said "unfortuntly appName has stopped" so can any body help me ?

This is my MainActivity class:

```
package com.tuto.ListViewApp2_SQLite;

import com.tuto.ListViewApp2_SQLite.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CountryDB countryDatabase = null;
    private Cursor countries = null;
    private ListView lvCountries = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Create the database helper
        CursorFactory factory = null;
        countryDatabase = new CountryDB(this, "countryDB", factory);

        String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Pop", "Area", BaseColumns._ID};
        lvCountries = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCountries);

        int[] targetLayoutIDs = {R.id.textName, R.id.textPop, R.id.textArea};

        SQLiteDatabase db = countryDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
        countries = db.query("countries", columnNames, null, null, null, null, null);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_item, 
                countries, columnNames, targetLayoutIDs, 0);    
        lvCountries.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        countryDatabase.close();
    }
}
```

And this my subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
package com.tuto.ListViewApp2_SQLite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class CountryDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String COUNTRY_TABLE_NAME = "countries";

    public CountryDB(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, name, factory, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dbCountries) {
        createTable(dbCountries);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dbCountries, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String dropSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COUNTRY_TABLE_NAME +";";
        dbCountries.execSQL(dropSQL);
        createTable(dbCountries);
    }

    private void createTable(SQLiteDatabase dbCountries){
        String createSQL = "CREATE TABLE "+COUNTRY_TABLE_NAME+" ("+
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                "Name TEXT, "+
                "Pop TEXT, "+
                "Area TEXT);";
        dbCountries.execSQL(createSQL);

        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + COUNTRY_TABLE_NAME +
                " (Name, Pop, Area) " +
                "SELECT 'South Korea' AS NAME, '41,769,726' AS Pop, '1,068,296' AS Area"+
                " UNION SELECT 'Australia', '21,766,711', '2,967,893'" +
                " UNION SELECT 'India' , '1,189,172,906', '1,269,338',+" +
                " UNION SELECT 'United States', '313,232,044', '3,718,691';";
        dbCountries.execSQL(insertSQL);

    }
}
```

Comment: And this is my subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `insertSQL` is not getting executed and fails. That's why your database is not getting upgraded. The insert query has a comma and a plus in the second last statement which is making the query invalid.

Try this-

```
 String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + COUNTRY_TABLE_NAME +
                " (Name, Pop, Area) " +
                "SELECT 'South Korea' AS NAME, '41,769,726' AS Pop, '1,068,296' AS Area"+
                " UNION SELECT 'Australia', '21,766,711', '2,967,893'" +
                " UNION SELECT 'India' , '1,189,172,906', '1,269,338'" +
                " UNION SELECT 'United States', '313,232,044', '3,718,691';";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a read only database already on your filesystem.  Its version is 0.  You're trying to upgrade it to version 1.  The problem is its read only, so you can't alter it.  Easiest solution would be to uninstall and reinstall the app, to get rid of the old one.  Or to check for the existence of the old database and delete it first.  Either of these will lose the data in it, but based on your onUpgrade code that's ok with you anyway.